# How to show menu items depending on the user's roles and the node type?

Tags: 8, navigation

I would like to show some menu items (merged with the main navigation menu) when viewing a node (full content) of a custom content type. Also, this menu items depend on user's roles. It could be something like contextual menu, but with the main menu. For example, I have a custom content type "invoice" and when an user is viewing an invoice, some new menu items should be shown, like "send by email", "pay",...

Comment: This could easily be done with a views block showing linked node titles with some contextual filters. But, having these links in the main menu you'll need to preprocess. There are a couple of contib modules that handle menu link access by `Role` which would get you part way. Have you looked at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_link_alter/8.8.x? With a hook you could set access by comparing current user role and content type.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally found how to do it. It was easier than I thought. I have created the menu and then place a block with this menu. In the block I can set the content type and controls I need.